# replacing toString using Groovy metaprogramming

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

In the following Groovy snippet, I attempt to replace both the `hashCode` and `toString` methods

```
String.metaClass.toString = {-> "override" }
String.metaClass.hashCode = {-> 22 }
```

But when I test it out, only the replacement of `hashCode` works

```
String s = "foo"
println s.hashCode()  // prints 22
println s.toString()  // prints "foo"
```

Is `toString` somehow a special case (possibly for security reasons)?

Answer (score 5):

See the first comment [on this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2599). It says about String's toString and other String related classes:

> (...) seems to be intent, it is probably a
>   good idea to have a faster invocation
>   for classes that don't allow
>   overriding toString().

Comment: How do you know which are the "classes that don't allow overriding toString()"?

Comment: I posted a new issue which hopefully should clear things up... http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4210

Comment: Thanks Tim, so I guess the short answer is "it's a bug"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [know defect](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3493).
Basically Groovy does not correctly override methods that are part of an interface implementation.

This works:

```
class T {
       def doIt() { true }
}

def t = new T()

assert t.doIt()
t.metaClass.doIt = { -> false }
assert !t.doIt()
```

This doesn't:

```
interface I {
       def doIt()
}

class T implements I {
       def doIt() { true }
}

def t = new T()

assert t.doIt()
t.metaClass.doIt = { -> false }
assert !t.doIt()
```

Because `toString()` in `String` comes from `CharSequence` the correct way to override would be:

```
CharSequence.metaClass.toString = {-> "silly"}
println "hello world".toString()
```